# Getting error as internet explorer can not display web page in PHP

Tags: php, wampserver

I have installed WAMP server for PHP.  MySQL extensions are enabled. I have written echo "hi" and run it on WAMP , it did show me proper output as Hi. When I use following snippet:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
```

I get message as Internet explorer can not displays web page.User Id and password are correct.
Replacing localhost with `127.0.0.1:3306` does not resolve this issue.

Comment: You might want to check your error logs when this happens. Are you missing a ';' ?

Comment: I have written below code. <?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 if (!$con)
   {
   echo("Cound Not Connect");
   }
 

 
mysql_close($con);
 ?></body></html>

Comment: Getting error as call to undefined function mysql_connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you posted in comments, it looms like the MySQL module might not be activated in your php configuration (php.ini).

To check this, write a blank page and put 'phpinfo();' in there. Look for installed modules and check whether MySQL is in there.

If not, edit your configuration accordingly.

Comment: MYSQL is insatlled and there are entries in PHP.ini file

Comment: I'm talking about the php MySQL package, not about MySQL itself. What entries specifically?